# Run command inside a process started using CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command, psexec

I want to write a batch file to run specific process, and run a command inside the process itself which runs inside the command prompt, then show results on console.

normally, I would open the CMD, type the process name/path: ggsci.exe, once it is running I run commands inside it (it actually connects to Oracle DB), for example :

[image]

How do I create a batch file does the same, this runs the process itself:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO running:
cd /d d:\
ggsci.exe
```

How to give ggsci.exe another command ?

Another option would be running the same using PsExec.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Oracle Golden Gate manual](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1221/gg-winux/GWUAD/getting-started-oracle-goldengate-process-interfaces.htm#GWUAD1097) :

To Input a Script

Use the following syntax from the command line of the operating system.

```
ggsci < input_file
```

**Update**

Probably this will work the same way:

`echo SELECT * from my.table|ggsci`

You can even use variables for dynamic scripts , though you you'll have to deal with the escaping the special symbols.

Other option is to generate a temp file and then use it:

```
echo SELECT * from my.table >temp_file
ggsci < temp_file
del /q /f temp_file
```

you can even use template [files and replace the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)

Comment: works perfectly, thanks, trying to pass a simple command "info all" instead of the having a file, any idea ?

Comment: I tried the same by saving to the %temp% directory but I could not achieve it, all good now. thank you !